# Run a 32 bit Powershell script on Sql Server Agent

Tags: powershell, 32bit-64bit, sql-server-agent

I have a powershell script that runs a 32 bit com object so when I run it in Powershell 64x it fails but runs fine in 86x

When I run it in a Sql Server Agent job it has the same 64x failure.

Is there a way around this? Like SSIS packages?

Comment: I ended up running CmdExec bat file that ran 32 Powershell file but I'm open to other ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly invoke the 32-bit version of PowerShell by calling it through the WOW64 path:

```
%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Using the -File command line argument you can pass the name of the script you would like to run.