# PowerShell Refresh Excel without opening excel file (Package scheduled execution issue with SQL Agent)

Tags: sql-server, excel, powershell, ssis, sql-agent

I have an SSIS Package I have developed with an 'Execute Process Task' and 'Data Flow Task'.  I am having an issue with execution of the package.

RESULTS: (Manual vs. Scheduled)

All processes are successful when run executed manually in 32-bit mode from ***VS*** and ***SSISDB*** when I login with a specific user profile 'GEORGES/BL0040EP'.

> 1. 'Execute Process Task' -- Run a powershell script to refresh excel connections and save the excel file.  *(SUCCESS)*
> 2. 'Data Flow Task' -- Reads the excel data and inserts it to SQL Server table.  *(SUCCESS)*

I am trying to run the package with ***SQL Agent*** (using a proxy account), and the process has some issues.

> 1. 'Execute Process Task' -- Run a powershell script to refresh excel connections *(DOES NOT WORK, NO ERROR MESSAGES)*.  Save the excel file *(SUCCESS)*.
> 2. 'Data Flow Task' -- Reads the excel data and inserts it to SQL Server table.  *(SUCCESS)*

PROBLEM:

> **The `powershell script to refresh the Excel file` seemingly does not get issued to the SSAS Server when run from `SQL Agent`.  Not "query issues successfully".  Not "query issues with permissions error".  Simply "query is not at all executed".  No permissions issues are logged or detected.**

I can tell because I ran SQL Profiler on the server.  When Agent calls the package there is no query activity.  When VS/SSISDIB calls the package I can see the query being issued.  Both successfully with user profile (GEORGES\bl0040ep); and unsuccessfully with permissions error with an unauthorized user profile (GEORGES\bl0040).

QUESTION:

> **Why would SQL Agent not run the query?**

I even added to the posh command `$env:UserName | Out-File -filepath` to output a text file containing the user name.  And the Proxy Account setup appears to be running under the expected user profile context.  Content of the text file is `bl0040ep`.

---

**Create Proxy Account**

[Creating a Proxy User to run an SSIS package in SQL Server Agent](https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2015/05/creating-a-proxy-user-to-run-an-ssis-package-in-sql-server-agent/)

```
USE master 
GO

-- Create a proxy credential for xp_cmdshell.
EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'GEORGES\bl0040ep', '!myPW!';--SELECT  * FROM [master].[sys].[credentials]

-- Grant execute permission on xp_cmdshell to the SQL Server login account. 
GRANT exec ON sys.xp_cmdshell TO [GEORGES\bl0040ep] 
GO

-- Create a credential containing the GEORGES account PowerGEORGES\PowerUser and its password
CREATE CREDENTIAL Credential_BL0040EP WITH IDENTITY = N'GEORGES\bl0040ep', SECRET = N'!myPW!'
GO

USE [msdb]
GO
-- Create a new proxy called SSISProxy and assign the PowerUser credentail to it
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_proxy @proxy_name=N'Proxy_BL0040EP',@credential_name=N'Credential_BL0040EP',@enabled=1

-- Grant SSISProxy access to the "SSIS package execution" subsystem
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem @proxy_name=N'Proxy_BL0040EP', @subsystem_id=11

-- Grant the login testUser the permissions to use SSISProxy
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_grant_login_to_proxy @login_name = N'GEORGES\bl0040ep', @proxy_name=N'Proxy_BL0040EP'
GO
```

**DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats_xlsx_ExcelRefresh.ps1**

[image]

```
# Refresh the excel workbook connections and save the updated file
$file = 'C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx'
$x1 = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$x1.Visible = $false
$x1.DisplayAlerts = $False
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yy")
# $filename = 'C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_Usage Stats ' + $enddate + '.xlsx'
$filename = 'C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\DatabaseSSAS_UsageStats.xlsx' 
$env:UserName | Out-File -filepath C:\SVN\BusinessAnalysts\ExcelTools\RefreshAll_process.txt
$wb = $x1.workbooks.Open($file)
$wb.refreshall() 

# REM: Use SLEEP to eliminate the message: "This will cancel a pending data refresh. Continue?"
Start-Sleep -Second 20
$wb.SaveAs($filename)
$wb.Close()
$x1.Quit()
Remove-Variable wb,x1
```

**SQL Profiler**

No activity is captured when running the package from SQL Agent.  When run from VS and SSISDB, a login error is captured.

*SQLProfiler_(VS/SSIDB-connectionerror_user-bl0040).png*

[image]

*SQLProfiler_(SQLAGENT-connection_no-activity).png*

There is no image to attache.  Simply there is no activity for the user (bl0040ep) when the package is run under the SQL Agent context.

---

Wed 02/06/2019 14:31:46.96

**UPDATE 1: System Desktop Folder**

I added ‘Desktop’ folder on System32, ran the job from SQL Agent, and the issues persists.  This was recommended on a similar issue reported on TechNet [Issues with simple script executed via SQL Server Agent](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99628eb9-d0c4-4736-87cc-6a69f43e5de2/issues-with-simple-script-executed-via-sql-server-agent?forum=winserverpowershell)...  `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`. The folder already existed on SysWOW64.

**UPDATE 2: PowerShell executable in 32-bit**

I have also tried to directly invoke the 32-bit version of PowerShell: `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. Still the excel refresh does not complete when run via SQL Agent with proxy account. Reference [Run a 32 bit Powershell script on Sql Server Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253543/run-a-32-bit-powershell-script-on-sql-server-agent)

**UPDATE 3: Windows Task Scheduler instead of SQL Agent Job**

I have tried a different scheduling method for the package execution (Windows Task Scheduler, instead of SQL Agent). The schedule completes but it behaves the exact same way that SQL Agent does... the query is not being sent to the datasource. Reference [Nirav's Diary, Schedule SSIS Package Without Deploying, 2-Windows Schedule Task](http://nirav.extreme-advice.com/2013/05/08/schedule-ssis-package-without-deploying/)

Comment: Under the Execution options tab for the job step is the Use 32 bit runtime option checked?

Comment: @Bruce - Yes, "32-bit runtime" is checked on the job step.  That was the solution to resolve the error message: "The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode.".

Comment: **UPDATE**: Based on a similar issue reported on TechNet [Issues with simple script executed via SQL Server Agent](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99628eb9-d0c4-4736-87cc-6a69f43e5de2/issues-with-simple-script-executed-via-sql-server-agent?forum=winserverpowershell)... I added ‘Desktop’ folder on System32, ran the job from SQL Agent, and the issues persists.  Folders: `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop`.  The folder already existed on SysWOW64.

Comment: **UPDATE**:  I have also tried to directly invoke the 32-bit version of PowerShell: `%SystemRoot%\syswow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.  Still the excel refresh does not complete when run via SQL Agent with proxy account.  Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253543/run-a-32-bit-powershell-script-on-sql-server-agent

Comment: **UPDATE**: I have tried a different scheduling method for the package execution (Windows Task Scheduler, instead of SQL Agent).  The schedule completes but it behaves the exact same way that SQL Agent does... the query is not being sent to the datasource.  Reference[Nirav's Diary, Schedule SSIS Package Without Deploying, 2-Windows Schedule Task](http://nirav.extreme-advice.com/2013/05/08/schedule-ssis-package-without-deploying/)

Comment: There's no info here about the SSIS log. That's the first place to look. It tells you whether the task was run and (sometimes) an error message. Do you have Excel installed on the SQL Server? Do you have that excel file sitting on the SQL Server in C drive? One big difference between running in VS and running in SQL Agent is that SQL Agent actually runs it on the server so all installed programs and drives are as though you are on the SQL Server

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - Yes, Excel is installed.  The excel file is in the C drive, as seen in the powershell script I posted.  All of the processes are currently being run on my workstation computer (SSIS, Excel, Agent, Task Scheduler), but the data source is on another server.  Regarding the SSIS Log File... the package is successful when run in 32-bit mode (I have been viewing the package execution report to read any messages).

Comment: So to be clear the SQL Server is installed and running on your local workstation also? What does the package log say in 64 bit mode?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid _ Yes, SQL Server is installed and running on my local workstation.  I'm not sure where to find the package log.  But when I run it in 64-bit mode, I have been running the package in 32-bit mode since 64-bit mode gave an error message.

Comment: So basically you're trying to automate something that is not friendly to automation - Excel, Excel Interop, message popups - all these things will cause issues. I guess the issue is in `$wb.refreshall()` but I'm not aware of a way to get any further information on what the issue is. Have you considered taking excel out of the equation and just inserting whatever SSAS data you're after directly into the database using other means?

Comment: And just for general information it would be useful to check the SSIS log. Assuming it's deployed to the SSIS Catalog, just righ click on the package to find logs. I guess they won't say much because the real issus in the PS script but at least you can confirm that the package is actually calling the step

Comment: Here's one way to query SSAS (Multidimensional) directly from T-SQL. https://technologyinsightscoffee.wordpress.com/2017/06/23/how-to-execute-a-mdx-query-in-sql-store-procedure/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - RE: SSIS Log - When I right click the package from Integration Services SSIS DB I choose "Reports> All Execution".  I do not see something that says SSIS Log.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - RE: Automation of Excel, Excel Interop, message popups - Yeah... I am doing something that seems simple that is apparently not simple, or "issue prone".  But it seems like it should be doable... and I've told myself this for about a week now.  I would hate to accept that [***automated schedule excel refresh with powershell***] is a "*complicated thing that can't be done*".  Maybe it is, or maybe there's a way to schedule this process.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - RE: Query SSAS Directly - I've chose to use Excel Power Query to load the data, because powerquery gives you some very flexible data manipulation tools for retreiving the dataset and adding complicated calculations.  I'm trying to "*have my cake, and eat it too*".  Because it seems simpler using the M language to manipulate the data for analyzing it later.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this by removing Excel from the picture.  Instead of Excel source I am now using the connector `.Net Providers for OleDb\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 2.0`.  There are a couple extra steps needed in the database to get the same dataset (using `SQL Views` instead of the `Excel Powerquery M`).

I lost this fight to Excel... it did not want to be automated.  I did end up still using the same CREDENTIALS and PROXY to schedule the job.

[image]